# botframework v4: send slack blocks in channelData property not working

Tags: javascript, botframework, slack

I'm using botframework v4 to deploy an azure bot. The bot will be used on both Teams and Slack channel.

The bot needs to send blocks layout to slack users. But when I put the blocks in channelData property, it always returns below issue

```
Error: Invalid ChannelData
    at new RestError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1397:28)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1849:37
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Here is the code snippet

```
await context.sendActivity({
                            "channelData": {
                                "blocks": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "image",
                                        "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/beagle.png",
                                        "alt_text": "Welcome to my bot"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }                            
                    )
```

I've tried adding "text" property to the payloads, the text will be replied by the bot correctly, but no image shows after the text.

And I've also tried other several ways, like put the blocks to attachments property, all didn't work.

Does someone knows what is the correct way to pass the blocks data to Slack?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly format a message for slack in bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451770/properly-format-a-message-for-slack-in-bot-framework)

Comment: TL~DR: Blocks are not yet supported. User attachments instead.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken thanks for your comment. I've tried attachments and that works. I will use these instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in the issue that @ErikKalkoken linked to, this feature currently isn't available. You have a couple of options:

1. Wait for [the feature](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5434) to be implemented. However, as one of the developers states:

> Based on my understanding of the roadmap right now, the activities endpoint will not be updated with support for Block Kit any time soon.

2. Since it looks like you're looking for a javascript answer, you can use [the BotKit Slack adapter](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/tree/master/packages/botbuilder-adapter-slack)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use attachments as @ErikKalkoken suggest.